# cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to write a small app that receives a welcome message via POST and returns it via GET. If I call only one method (GET or POST), there are no problems, but as soon as I call GET and POST, I get the following message:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\aph\IdeaProjects\hello-world-node\ExpressApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\aph\IdeaProjects\hello-world-node\ExpressApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at Greeting.find (C:\Users\aph\IdeaProjects\hello-world-node\ExpressApp\routes\hello.js:16:13)
    at C:\Users\aph\IdeaProjects\hello-world-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4568:16
    at C:\Users\aph\IdeaProjects\hello-world-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4315:12
    at process.nextTick (C:\Users\aph\IdeaProjects\hello-world-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\completeMany.js:35:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at C:\Users\aph\IdeaProjects\hello-world-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4570:13
    at C:\Users\aph\IdeaProjects\hello-world-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4315:12
    at process.nextTick (C:\Users\aph\IdeaProjects\hello-world-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\completeMany.js:35:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const router = express.Router();

const Greeting = mongoose.model("Greeting", new Schema({message: String}));

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    Greeting.find({message: "Hello World!"}, (err, greetings) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.send(JSON.stringify(greetings));
    });

    res.send("There are no greetings!");
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {useNewUrlParser: true});
    new Greeting(req.body).save()
        .then(() => {
            res.send('success');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send("Error: " + err)
        });
});


module.exports = router;
```

I scanned [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client?rq=1) but could not find a solution for my problem.

Comment: In `.find()` callback check for `greetings` exists and `length` for example and send response there only with `if/else` clause. `res.send` is getting called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Greeting.find` is an async function so the line `res.send("There are no greetings!");` runs before the callback of `Greeting.find` runs which means the response `'There are no greetings!'` is sent to the client before the callback ever runs.

Then in `Greeting.find` callback you're trying to send a response to the client again which causes the error.